# Elastic Load Balancing w.r.t EC2 Memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

So basically I have this EC2 Linux Instance with 8GB memory and I am having multiple applications running on it. It doesn't happen often, but when there is huge traffic, 8GB memory isn't enough, and the whole instance stops responding. To make things work like normal, I have to reboot the instance every time.

I have heard that Elastic Load Balancing might scale the memory as required. But how to achieve that? Is there any other way to solve my problem? Is there a tutorial that'd guide me through this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have heard that Elastic Load Balancing might scale the memory

ELB **does not scale** a memory of your instance. Instead it can distribute your connections among multiple instances. Thus, instead of having one instance which servers all your traffic, you would have two or more. In this setup, ELB would **distribute traffic** equally among your instances, so that collectively they can server more connections then a single instance.

What's more you usually use ELB with [autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/what-is-amazon-ec2-auto-scaling.html) so that the number of instances is adjusted **automatically** up and down, depending on the incoming traffic.

> Is there a tutorial that'd guide me through this?

You can start with offical AWS tutorial [Set up a scaled and load-balanced application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-register-lbs-with-asg.html) .